# How to import util module in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

isDeepStrictEqual() method to do object comparison but am blocked by error:

```
util.isDeepStrictEqual() is not a function
```

1. According to official documentation: this method was introduced in v9.0.0 and I am using Node v12: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_isdeepstrictequal_val1_val2
2. I confirmed this method is available on command line:

   ```
   D:\>node
   Welcome to Node.js v12.18.2.
   Type ".help" for more information.
   > require("util").isDeepStrictEqual({'name': 'john'}, {'sex': 'male'})
   false
   > require("util").isDeepStrictEqual({'sex': 'john'}, {'sex': 'male'})
   false
   > require("util").isDeepStrictEqual({'sex': 'male'}, {'sex': 'male'})
   true
   ```
3. Here is my code:

   ```
   class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        var util = require('util');
        var obj1 = {name: 'john'};
        var obj2 = {sex: 'male'};
        var result = util.isDeepStrictEqual(obj1, obj2);
    }
   ```

Comment: reactjs runs on the web browser, nodejs runs on the console, they are two completely different environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont know if you have done this so first do this
[util-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/util)

```
npm install util
```

And adding on to the @3limin4t0r answer I don't think util should be declared in the constructor.

have it as a global constant outside the class

for example

```
const util = require('util');

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 42;
  }

  bar(callback) {
    callback(null, this.a);
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();

const naiveBar = util.promisify(foo.bar);
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined
// naiveBar().then(a => console.log(a));

naiveBar.call(foo).then((a) => console.log(a)); // '42'

const bindBar = naiveBar.bind(foo);
bindBar().then((a) => console.log(a)); // '42'
```

which was the example for promisify right below [Util doc(isDeepStrictEqual)](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_isdeepstrictequal_val1_val2)

So either use it as a global constant or use it directly as you have used in the command line.

Comment: Thanks but this is not working. Same error persists: util.isDeepStrictEqual is not a function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this with "util" name:

```
import * as util from 'util';
```